# Making objects with Java in Xcode - interact with program

Tags: java, xcode, class, object, ide

I am using Xcode 9 and I am learning Java programming. 
I was wondering if there is a way, like in other Java development programs, to create a sort of IDE within Xcode in order to interact with the code while it "runs" by creating and manipulating objects?

For example, if I have a class `Student` defined in a Java file, is there a way, within Xcode for me to enter code such as `Student Joe = new Student("Joe");` and then call this object's methods such as `Joe.getName();` without having to develop an application?

I am looking for a way to do this as I prefer coding in Xcode over other Java development applications.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you use IntelliJ Idea to do your java development not Xcode... just my 2 cents. But no you need to develop an application or use the website repl.it to execute your code inline through a web browser.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look into IntelliJ.